# chrome extension context menu, not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

so i'm trying to build a simple extension that adds an option to the menu when you right click
a link, i wrote the "code" that reEdit the link but for some reason i dont even see the option when i right click a link.
i have tried everything(i have to admit i dont have a any experience with javaScript or chrome extensions)

here is my manifest code:

```
 {
  "name": "EditURL",
  "description": "editing URL in SERET website",
  "version": "0.7",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and js code:

```
function killAdd(info)
{
var domain = info.selectionText;
var index = domain.lastIndexOf(":");
domain = domain.substring(index - 4);
 chrome.tabs.create({url: domain})
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Addkill", contexts: ["link"], onclick: function KillAdd(onClickData)});
```

any ideas???

Comment: In your last line: `function KillAdd(onClickData)` is not a valid function declaration!

Comment: so how you would fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Addkill",
  contexts: ["link"],
  onclick: killAdd
});
```

> i have to admit i dont have a any experience with javaScript or chrome
>   extensions

In all honesty, I would advise you to first learn JavaScript and then to start creating Chrome extensions.